# Android Picasso not loading img to view from handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, picasso

I trying to get pic url in Thread and load in Picasso, but image not shows. Url is valid. Picasso not load placeholder and error img. Without Thread and Handler works fine.

```
     final String[] sss = {""};
    final Handler hh = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Picasso.with(context).load(sss[0]).resize(500, 281).centerCrop().into(mainHolder.ivPreview);
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sss[0] = getUrl();
            hh.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        }
    });
    th.start();
```

Comment: Use `hh.sendEmptyMessage(0);` after `getUrl()` method complete

Comment: hh.sendEmptyMessage(0); already after getUrl(). or I dont understand?

Comment: Make sure that your context is not null.

Comment: @baralgin1003 do you have to use `Handler` to load image with `Picasso`? `Picasso` already downloading images in background.

Comment: @Yupi i tryed without handler. The problem is that I get URL in the background and the Picasso does not load from the background thread either

Comment: @Ankita context is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Check again getUrl() and context. This code work for me.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        final Context context=this;
        final String[] sss = {""};
        final Handler hh = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Picasso.with(context).load(sss[0]).resize(500, 281).centerCrop().into(imageView);
            }
        };
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sss[0] = "http://teleflora.edgesuite.net/images/products/HW0_706075.jpg";
                hh.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            }
        });
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @baralgin1003 So what actually didn't work? Where did you make mistake?

Comment: @yupi I didnt know. I fully rewrite my method and its work